# ActiveRecord getter breaks validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I need to validate credit card number.

```
model Billing
  validates :card, credit_card_number: true, allow_nil: true
```

Validation gem code:

```
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors.add(attribute, options[:message] || :invalid) unless credit_card_valid?(value, extract_brands(record, options))
  end
```

It works ok.
But then I try to override geter this way:

```
   def card
    "****#{self[:card][-4,4]}" if self[:card]
   end
```

Validation fails.
when I monkey patched validates_each like that:

```
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    value = record[attribute]
    record.errors.add(attribute, options[:message] || :invalid) unless credit_card_valid?(value, extract_brands(record, options))
  end
```

It back to work well.
Is it correct validation behavior, to validates getters instead of persisted values (validates_each first variant is follows guide).
Or what is preffered way to solve my problem? 
Update: Activemodel/Activerecord version: 4.2.3

Comment: Have you try to define your own validation ? Defining something like 
    class CustomCreditCardValidator < ActiveModel::Validator. This would prevent the use of monkey patch

Comment: Why would you be surprised that `****************1234` is not valid credit card number?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the method you defined is not a model concern - it is a view concern and as such should be moved to a helper or presenter. This is however very common practice to have such methods within the model, so I wouldn't say that's a huge problem.

You can easily get around the whole problem, by picking the other name for your method:

```
def starred_card
  card && "****#{card[-4,4]}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you override the getter method (as you have done here), you have to write a custom validation method.

For example, here is a simple validation that allows nil and ensures the card number is a string of 16 digits.

```
validate :correct_credit_card_number

def correct_credit_card_number
    if self[:card] && self[:card] !~ /^\d{16}$/
        errors.add(:card, "is not in the right format")
    end
end
```